# How to Properly Decode Hex Values in RTF

Tags: python, character-encoding, nlp, rtf

Unfortunately this one goes down two rabbit holes, text encodings and RTF. But here it is.

### Background

I am working on an NLP text pipeline where we need to convert RTF to plain text, in other words we need to remove the RTF control characters and leave the text content intact. We are building the pipeline in python and it has several requirements that prevent us from using something like Apache Tikka in production.

I know that RTF can contain hex values such as `\'a9` if the author of the document typed a non-ascii character. I also know that the first sequence of control characters in the document specifies how to decode these hex values, e.g. `\ansicpg1252`. For example, in this case the presence of `\ansicpg1252` at the beginning of the document means that `\'a9` should be interpreted as unicode code point `00A9 (COPYRIGHT SIGN)` as per [the windows-1252 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

### Question

I came across an RTF document with `\ansicpg1252` in the first set of control characters, however there are several places in the document where the following hex literals appear, `\'81\'aa`. This is confusing becuase `0x81` is undefined in the `windows-1252` encoding. I thought maybe it could be `utf-8`, however it isn't defined in `utf-8` either.

WordPad.exe represents these two bytes with this character: ↑

Apache Tikka uses the same character, ↑

This character corresponds to unicode code point `2191 (Upwards Arrow)`, and as it turns out our mystery bytes, `0x81AA`, are the result of encoding this character using the [Windows Code Page 932 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)), which contains Japanese characters.

For reference, the full context of those two bytes in the RTF document is

```
\plain\f1\fs20 \'81\'aa\plain\f0\fs20
```

and the document contains this entry in the `\fonttbl` group:

```
{\f1\fmodern\fcharset128\fprq1 MS Mincho;}
```

which, as far as I understand, means that any text following `\f1` should be rendered using the `MS Mincho` font, which kind of makes sense since `MS Mincho` contains Japanese glyphs. But how would an RTF parser know that `0x81AA` should be decoded using `Windows Code Page 932` and not `ansicpg1252` as specified in the first line of the file? Do I need to know that certain fonts imply certain encodings?

My best guess is that it has something to do with the part of the `\fonttbl` entry that says `\fcharset128`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have a full example file I could see? I'm interested to verify if RTF Parser Kit (https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit) handles it correctly... if so it should be straightforward to trace how the encoding is being determined.

Comment: Unfortunately it's medical text, so I won't post it. But the links in your answer are excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting a comment, I did a bit more digging...

The `fcharset` argument comes from a fixed set of values, which map to the encoding used. Here's an example:

https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rtfparserkit/parser/standard/FontCharset.java

From memory I *think* I picked these up from Microsoft's RTF spec document (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725)